# How to set types when creating a new class instance on TypeScript from a static context and avoid circular type dependencies

Tags: typescript, inheritance, constructor, typescript-typings

I have spent a day on trying various hacks and techniques when solving this and now I'm asking the community to share some knowledge.

Basically there is an abstract model and repository classes which are extended by other simple concrete classes. Nothing special.

The code provided below 100% works for me when compiled, but has a two issues with types:

- Circular type dependency in generics (`Generic type 'Repository<M>' requires 1 type argument(s).`)
- An issue with a dynamic constructor (`Argument of type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: unknown[]) => Model<Repository<any>>'.
  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.(2345)`)

Here is the code (and [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=47&pln=18&pc=22#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgCoB8AFNHCgFyIDeiYaA7kQHQsYoDmAzpeANZhx6YANoBdAJSU8iAL4AaRCyZsuPMP0EiJ1AFCJE6KCBRI69ZFDLNWHTuIDcOmTp0QANhk6dEAYThu3NGh4MHxENAAPbDAAE28AWTgYtDcCXX0IBE4oFBBSFCIABxAAIzcYCEQYbABbbkQ8MXF02Rd9DACiZqo9fQM0IxNEKAALGE4marQ6x31nXvYBohhYyMowEBqStBRu3v1DYyRR8cnazmEV5IjRWdb5jBLslAxoZA8vRETktxwAJXCUTQsW8fzQhTgnGqZAAnjgMGAYQQ0j19JFxlBvABeRDADqcNCOXpgDA1NAAfkozxW7CJGSyOTylgKhRQcGw0DQMX6EKhzJhlD%20ChU9T4AiEez6iAA8iUAFZBKDKLwwdhgIgnTjC2ziXrzfQ1Ni8ACiEQxnC6LX0mqY6Oy2OGuUJbT6hyGmruzgeTxyryg708oPBkOhKDh8UB0TiXySKXhiORLWKZQqiBqsbciBx3xSdMQyfKlWAbJqAEEUC8YUQ2JW1BohE0rcgGWmMIVClys4gaxgYUxDYUiMtmliUfs%20pkwNk013UJhsBqxhN0z8FJqFDAHC6pTV%200bTeaunmpW6kDU7nNmp4vmJj-1BqYGL5-IFgggcPFiAOOzEt3MXQWqbZFgqbFnAZYVr2H7ED2AqIGKmiNqiroDEcyDoFgaCLuM4hMGBEGVtWkEwn%209wuO4ga%20OUwL%20pEUYJBm-zBnysLxkiY76DE4EYCsXYAOTuDANGcHxjjzBRnw%20NRYBQGCvKhjCkbAtGckhvyOBSUJMkcYgXGGrxOICdJmKiU45EtrBXbCDQJJkpQfEAFJwCMYB8bICg2aSaD2QAyqSCKjBgbkyLcrgtiMMIxC82AxJpwldnFMmqSxYZ4SW5aEbBW5hVO-hoEwbhwOwRARVFmGxcZEyLFARAAAy4bZaBbpOnB5QVRUlZF0VcolmJMNVRAAIwNV54hAA)):

```
// @see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function

function create<T>(ctor: { new(...args: unknown[]): T }, ...args: unknown[]) {
  return new ctor(...args);
}

// Some real-world example, see the problematic classes below
class Collection<T extends Model> {
  constructor(public items: T[]) {
  }

  all() {
    return this.items;
  }

  get(index: number) {
    return this.items[index];
  }
}

// Issue #1. In fact, <any> is not what I want here, but a relevant type
abstract class Model<R extends Repository<any>> {
  exists = false;

  name?: string;

  constructor(protected repository: R, args: unknown) {
    Object.assign(this, args);
  }

  markExists() {
    this.exists = true;

    return this;
  }
}

abstract class Repository<M extends Model<any>> {
  public model = Model;

  public fromArray(array: unknown[]) {
    const mapped = array.map((i) => {
      // Issue #2
      const m = create(this.model, this, i);

      m.markExists();

      return m;
    }) as M[];

    return new Collection<M>(mapped);
  }

  public static fromArray<M>(array: unknown[]) {
    // Another case of issue #2
    return create(this).fromArray(array);
  }
}

class Client extends Model<Repository<any>> {
  domain = 'clients';
}

class ClientRepository extends Repository<Client> {
  domain = 'clients';
}

const array = [{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Samantha' }];
const hydratedClients = ClientRepository.fromArray(array);

console.log(hydratedClients.get(0).name); // John
console.log(hydratedClients.get(1).name) // Samantha
```

The `create` function [is borrowed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function) from the official TS FAQ.

Any idea how to resolve those two issues (or at least issue #2)?

Anyways, thanks for all advices in advance!

Comment: were you able to figure this out at all - I'm having similar issues with typescript & generics